# "Hurried times" grammar/usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While I know that most songs don't necessarily follow proper grammar or usage, or even need to make any sense I couldn't help but be troubled by a line in a song I heard.

```
"These are hurried times"
```

It felt as though I had heard this phrase somewhere before, and after some quick searches I saw a handful of news articles that use the same phrasing in the title, but quite possibly as tribute to a favorite song of the author.

My interpretation of the quote (which may be completely wrong) is that within the present era, things are done in a rush.

However, when I try to read this as is, that the times are hurried, that the times themselves are being rushed through. Is it correct to use the word `hurried` or any word pertaining to rate of execution to describe time/eras? To help explain this a bit better, would `"These are slowed times"` also be correct in this sense, to describe that an era actions are performed at a leisurely pace?

Comment: If it's not the times that are hurried, then perhaps it's an example of [**hypallage**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage).  Classic example: in a *drunken brawl*, the brawl is not actually drunk.

Comment: Can't say I've heard of 'hypallage' before but this describes this perfectly! I'll definitely be remembering this type of usage in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "These are hurried times" means that people or society in the era *felt* "hurried". There are similar phrases:

> These are troubled times.
>
> These are fortunate times.

You can certainly say:

> These are slowed times.

This would mean something akin to:

> In those times, people/things/technology were slow.

It may not be immediately obvious what you mean but it could work with additional context.